# View state error when large number of records returned

Tags: apex, visualforce, list, viewstate

I am getting view state error for my code.

Apex class:

```
    public with sharing class zisQuoteSourceListOnQuoteDetailCon {

      public String zisQuoteId {get;set;}
       public String zisQuotesourceId {get;set;}
      public ZI_Quote__c updateqtlst{get;set;}
       public ZI_Quote__c quotelist{get;set;}
       public List<ZIS_Quote_Source__c> ziquotesourcelist{get;set;}
       public String qtName='';

       public User activeUser{get;set;}

    public zisQuoteSourceListOnQuoteDetailCon(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

     zisQuoteId= ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');
      try {
     quotelist=[select id,name,RecordType.name,Quote_Valid_for_approval__c,quote_country__c,Quote_Type__c,Status__c,Hours_Remaining__c,ownerId from ZI_Quote__c where id=:zisQuoteId limit 1];      
     }catch(Exception e){}
     String userName = UserInfo.getUserName();
         activeUser = [Select id,name,Profile.name,Email,Organization__c,Country__c From User where Username = : userName limit 1];

            if(quotelist.Quote_Valid_for_approval__c==true){         
         if(activeUser.Profile.name =='ZIS Coordinator' || activeUser.Profile.name =='ZIS Buyer & Manager' || activeUser.Profile.name =='ZIS Director approval' || activeUser.Profile.name =='System Administrator'){       
     ziquotesourcelist = [Select id,name,Source_Type__c,ZISQuote__r.name,ZISQuote__r.Quote_Valid_for_approval__c,ItemId__c,Item_Description__c,Full_Description__c,ZISQuote__c,UOM__c,Required_Qty__c,Final_Req__c,Unit_Price__c,Valid_for_approval__c,Total_Amount__c,
                      ZISQuote__r.Status__c,ZISQuote__r.Hours_Remaining__c,ZISQuote__r.RecordType.name,SHIP_TO_ORGANIZATION__c,Item_Line__c,Item__c,PR_Number__c,PO_Number__c from ZIS_Quote_Source__c where ZISQuote__c=:zisQuoteId order by Item_Line__c]; 
         }else if(activeUser.Profile.name =='ZISVendors'){
                ziquotesourcelist = [Select id,name,Source_Type__c,ZISQuote__r.name,ZISQuote__r.Quote_Valid_for_approval__c,ItemId__c,Item_Description__c,Full_Description__c,ZISQuote__c,UOM__c,Required_Qty__c,Final_Req__c,Unit_Price__c,Valid_for_approval__c,Total_Amount__c,
                      ZISQuote__r.Status__c,ZISQuote__r.Hours_Remaining__c,ZISQuote__r.RecordType.name,SHIP_TO_ORGANIZATION__c,Item_Line__c,Item__c,PR_Number__c,PO_Number__c  from ZIS_Quote_Source__c where ZISQuote__c=:zisquoteId and Valid_for_approval__c=true order by Item_Line__c];
               system.debug('********SUPLLIER**********'+ziquotesourcelist);
               }
              } else{
             ziquotesourcelist = [Select id,name,Source_Type__c,ZISQuote__r.name,ZISQuote__r.Quote_Valid_for_approval__c,ItemId__c,Item_Description__c,Full_Description__c,ZISQuote__c,UOM__c,Required_Qty__c,Final_Req__c,Unit_Price__c,Valid_for_approval__c,Total_Amount__c,
                      ZISQuote__r.Status__c,ZISQuote__r.Hours_Remaining__c,ZISQuote__r.RecordType.name,SHIP_TO_ORGANIZATION__c,Item_Line__c,Item__c,PR_Number__c,PO_Number__c from ZIS_Quote_Source__c where ZISQuote__c=:zisQuoteId order by Item_Line__c]; 

                   }

    if(ziquotesourcelist!=null &&  ziquotesourcelist.size()>0){
    qtName=ziquotesourcelist[0].ZISQuote__r.name;
    }else{

     updateqtlst=[select id,name,RecordType.name,Quote_Type__c,Status__c,Hours_Remaining__c from ZI_Quote__c where id=:zisQuoteId limit 1];      
     qtName=updateqtlst.name;

    }
    }

    ///////////////////////Redirect on MassEdit Page////////////// 
      public PageReference massEditPage(){
      String userName = UserInfo.getUserName();
      User activeUser = [Select id, name,user.profile.name,Country__c From User where Username = : userName limit 1];

      User ownercountry = [Select id, name,user.profile.name,Country__c From User where id=:quotelist.ownerId  limit 1];

      system.debug('###########'+ownercountry.Country__c);



      if(quotelist.quote_country__c =='Saudi Arabia'){
      if(activeUser.profile.name=='ZISVendors')
      {
        PageReference massEditPage = new PageReference('/'+'apex/zisQuotesForMassEditItem?isdtp=vw&zisquoteId='+zisQuoteId);
           massEditPage.getParameters().put('inline','0');
            massEditPage.setRedirect(true);  
          return massEditPage;
      }else{
       PageReference massEditPage = new PageReference('/'+'apex/zisQuotesForMassEditItem?zisquoteId='+zisQuoteId);
        massEditPage.setRedirect(true);  
        return massEditPage;
      }
      }else if(quotelist.quote_country__c =='India'){
      if(activeUser.profile.name=='ZISVendors')
      {
        PageReference massEditPage = new PageReference('/'+'apex/zisIndiaMassEditPage?isdtp=vw&zisquoteId='+zisQuoteId);
           massEditPage.getParameters().put('inline','0');
            massEditPage.setRedirect(true);  
          return massEditPage;
      }else{
       PageReference massEditPage = new PageReference('/'+'apex/zisIndiaMassEditPage?zisquoteId='+zisQuoteId);
        massEditPage.setRedirect(true);  
        return massEditPage;
      }


      } else if(quotelist.quote_country__c =='Vietnam'){

      if(activeUser.profile.name=='ZISVendors')
      {
        PageReference massEditPage = new PageReference('/'+'apex/zisVNDMassEditPage?isdtp=vw&zisquoteId='+zisQuoteId);
           massEditPage.getParameters().put('inline','0');
            massEditPage.setRedirect(true);  
          return massEditPage;
      }else{
       PageReference massEditPage = new PageReference('/'+'apex/zisVNDMassEditPage?zisquoteId='+zisQuoteId);
        massEditPage.setRedirect(true);  
        return massEditPage;
      }
      }
      return null;

      }

      ///////////////////////////////Redirect to Edit Page////////////////////
       public PageReference quoteEditPage(){
     //PageReference qtEditPage = new PageReference('/a0Q/e?CF00NM00000012fHM='+qtName+'&CF00NM00000012fHM_lkid='+zisQuoteId+'&retURL=%2F'+zisQuoteId);
  PageReference qtEditPage = new PageReference(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/a0Z/e?CF00ND0000005FlWA='+qtName+'&CF00ND0000005FlWA_lkid='+zisQuoteId);

        qtEditPage.setRedirect(true);  
        return qtEditPage ;

      }

         public PageReference MassQuoteSourcePage(){
         zisQuoteId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
         PageReference page = new PageReference('/apex/ImportDataFromCSVPage?id='+zisQuoteId);
         page.setRedirect(true);
         return page;

      }

      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////Redirect to quote source detail page////////////////////////////////////////

       public PageReference quotesrcdetailPage(){

  PageReference detailpg= new PageReference('/'+zisQuotesourceId);

        detailpg.setRedirect(true);  
        return detailpg;

      }

}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="ZI_Quote__c" extensions="zisQuoteSourceListOnQuoteDetailCon"  >
<style>
    a:hover {
        background:#82CAFA; /*BG color is a must for IE6*/
        text-decoration:none;
    } 
    a.tooltip span {
        display:none; 
        padding:2px 3px; 
        margin-left:8px; 
        width:300px;
    }
    a.tooltip:hover span{
        display:inline; 
        position:relative; 
        background:#D0D0D0; 
        border:1px solid #cccccc; 
        color:#000000;
    }
</style>
<apex:form >
<base target="_top" ></base>
  <apex:pageBlock >
  <table width="100%">
  <tr>
   <td width="50%" align="right">
 <apex:commandButton action="{!quoteEditPage}" value="New ZISQuote Source" rendered="{!quotelist.RecordType.name=='ZIS Openlayout for New Data'}"/> 
  </td>
   <td>
 <apex:commandButton action="{!MassQuoteSourcePage}" value="Mass Import Quote Source" rendered="{!quotelist.RecordType.name=='ZIS Openlayout for New Data'}"/> 
  </td>

  <td width="50%"  align="left">
<!-- <apex:commandButton action="{!massEditPage}" value="Mass Edit ZISQuote Details" rendered="{!($Profile.Name=='ZISVendors' && quotelist.Status__c=='Submitted To Supplier')  || ($Profile.Name!='ZISVendors' && (quotelist.Status__c=='Open' || (quotelist.Status__c =='Received From Supplier' && quotelist.Hours_Remaining__c!=null && quotelist.Hours_Remaining__c<=0)))}"/>  -->
 <apex:commandButton action="{!massEditPage}" value="Mass Edit ZISQuote Details" rendered="{!($Profile.Name=='ZISVendors' && quotelist.Status__c=='Submitted To Supplier')  || ($Profile.Name!='ZISVendors' && (quotelist.Status__c=='Open' || (quotelist.Status__c =='Received From Supplier' && quotelist.Hours_Remaining__c!=null && quotelist.Hours_Remaining__c<=0)))}"/>  
  </td>

   </tr>
    </table>
       <apex:pageblockTable value="{!ziquotesourcelist}" var="sourceItem" >

       <apex:column >
       <apex:commandLink action="{!quotesrcdetailPage}" target="_blank" rendered="{!sourceItem.Source_Type__c=='Manual'}" >   

     <center>  <apex:image url="{!$Resource.ZISEditIcon}" title="Edit"  width="20px" height="20px" />  </center>
                        <apex:param assignTo="{!zisQuotesourceId }" name="zisQuotesourceId "  value="{!sourceItem.id}" />

        </apex:commandLink>    

        </apex:column>


           <apex:column headerValue="Approval Status ">
                   <apex:outputField value="{!sourceItem.Valid_for_approval__c}"/>
              </apex:column>

              <apex:column headerValue="Item Line#">
                   <apex:outputField value="{!sourceItem.Item_Line__c}"/>

              </apex:column>
               <apex:column headerValue="Item(Part Mark)">
                   <apex:outputField value="{!sourceItem.Item__c}"/>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Item Description"><span class="tooltip" title="{!sourceItem.Full_Description__c}">
                   <apex:outputField value="{!sourceItem.Item_Description__c}"/></span>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="UOM">
                   <apex:outputField value="{!sourceItem.UOM__c}"/>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Final Qty">
                   <apex:outputField value="{!sourceItem.Final_Req__c}"/>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Ship To Organization">
                   <apex:outputField value="{!sourceItem.SHIP_TO_ORGANIZATION__c}"/>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Unit Price">
                   <apex:outputField value="{!sourceItem.Unit_Price__c}" rendered="{!$Profile.Name=='ZISVendors' || ((sourceItem.ZISQuote__r.Status__c=='Received From Supplier' ||sourceItem.ZISQuote__r.Status__c =='In Process' || sourceItem.ZISQuote__r.Status__c =='Approved' ) && sourceItem.ZISQuote__r.Hours_Remaining__c!= null && (sourceItem.ZISQuote__r.Hours_Remaining__c==0 || sourceItem.ZISQuote__r.Hours_Remaining__c<0))}"/>
              </apex:column>


  </apex:pageblockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here I observed that List is having more than 600 records.
Is that list size hampering my code.?
Please help.

Comment: It can be go to your user record detail page and enable  "Show View State in Development Mode" and check what is hampering your code. from developer toolbar on your vf page

Comment: As an aside, you have a lot of string based URLs as page references. There are APIs to all those page references `Page.PageName` for Visualforce and `StandardController.view()` for your detail page reference. I tend to shun string based URLs as page reference and use them as a last resort.

Answer (score 2):

A view state error will not be down to any fundamental bug in the way you wrote your code, rather it will be down to how you designed what you planned to do.

The view state is a serialized encrypted version of your controller data used to maintain state between requests. To ensure a maximum efficiency in communication between client (browser) and server Visualforce has a hard limit to view state size. You have exceeded that limit.

What can you do to reduce view state?

- Query fewer records or set a row limit
- Query fewer fields per record
- Make variables `transient`
- Use pagination to return a subset of records per page

There are some good [articles](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State) on optimizing view state as well as documentation in the visualforce [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_visualforce_best_practices.meta/salesforce_visualforce_best_practices/pages_best_practices_perf_code_view_state.htm). I would suggest you spend some time understanding how it works.

For your page, here are some steps I would consider:

- Pagination with `StandardSetController` and a wrapper class for your mass edit.
- Setting the `LIMIT` clause in your SOQL
- Better yet, make `LIMIT` dynamic so the user can change how many records are returned per page

Comment: I don't have time to optimize the view state, can I just catch the exception and display a custom message telling the user their search is too big ?